# Mediawiki API - Throwing error getting previous date

Tags: api, mediawiki-api, semantic-mediawiki

I am new in this api which is `MediaWiki web service API`.
I am trying to pull data in above table of this url: https://lessonslearned.em.se.com/lessons/Main_Page

I'm testing it using its sandbox: https://lessonslearned.em.se.com/lessons/Special:ApiSandbox

Now, I can view the source of the page for example:

`{{#ask:[[Category:Lesson]][[Has region::NAM]][[Creation date::>{{#time: r | -1 year}}]]|format=count}}`

Above code should return lessons from NAM 12 months ago which has a value of `1` based on the table. But I am getting an error in this part `[[Creation date::>{{#time: r | -1 year}}]]`.

Error message:`{ "error": { "query": [ "\"Thu, 31 Mar 2022 03:50:49 +0000  -1 03202233103\" contains an extrinsic dash or other characters that are invalid for a date interpretation." ] } }`

I tried to break the code in each part and found out that the root cause is the `hyphen(-)` in `-1 year`. I also check the documentation of the `time parser function`(https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Extension:ParserFunctions##time) and they have samples similar to this, But in my case it is not working.

Hope someone can give me at least reference for this problem. Thanks!

Comment: I suspect the problem is the date formating "r", you should try {{#time : U | - 1 year }}

Comment: @IRA1777 same error. But `+` sign works.

Comment: I can confirm you that this expression format works : [[Has transaction date::>{{#time:Y-m-d|now -1 year}}]]

Comment: @IRA1777 What action you're using? I can't sill make it work in the api sandbox

Comment: My bad, I wasn't using sandbox. But anyway, parser functions like "time" won't work there.

Comment: @IRA1777 you have any reference about that? Thanks